# jquery conflicts with ajax control toolkit september / october release 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've recently upgraded our project to use the october 2013 release of the ajax control toolkit in order to use the upgrades to both the html editor extender and the ajax file uploader (asp.net 4.0 project using c#, jquery 1.9.0, jquery-ui 1.9.2 and ajax control toolkit previously january 2013)

Once installed, our project starts suffering from loss of $ and other jquery plugins failing due to this. (firebug has shown $.ui to be undefined on some of our scripts but informs of version 1.9.1)

The toolkit now spits out version 1.9.1 of jquery which is happening after we load jquery 1.9.0 and our other scripts.

Apparently the toolkit uses jQuery.noConflict to avoid this kind of problem happening, but it is still happening for us.

I've downloaded the source code for the toolkit, and stopped it from scripting jquery 1.9.1 to the page, but this hasn't fixed anything. It seems like the internals of the toolkit are using an even newer version for creating its own jquery controls referenced from cdn.

Has anybody else suffered this issue and overcome it?

Comment: If this product wants a newer version of jQuery, giving it an older one is probably a bad idea. The `x.0` versions of jQuery are not the best thing to base a product release on.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded our jquery version to test. It made no difference. I'm sure you're correct, however we have larger testing implications for a jquery upgrade. Our ajax implementation is much smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problems disappeared once I added an AjaxControlToolkit.config file to the solution and referenced only the ajax controls I needed, so perhaps one of them was causing a conflict.

I notice now that there is a new release (December) of the ajax control toolkit that actually allows you to configure removal their version of jquery.